# Adobe Acrobat Pro 9 Link tool doesn't resize the link area very precisely

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I try to select an area of my pdf to make a link, but the selected box seems to only be allowed to be certain sizes.  It's selecting two whole lines of text.  I can't resize the link area very precisely using the "handles" on the corners of the link area, as directed by the help file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering myself:  Change the grid size in Acrobat:  Edit / Preferences / Units & Guides / and reduce the size of the "Width between lines" and "Height between lines" values.  Then selections can be more precise, the grid is now smaller.